# Cannot find application.php

Tags: zend-framework

hello am trying to install zend framework again after formating my machine but i keep getting this error...i have already done one project from previous installation but this time installation has just failed..

```
 >>>Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]:       to          open stream:  
No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\public\index.php on line 18



Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required     'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\home\library;â€œ.') in C:\xampp \htdocs\home\public\index.php on line 18
            This is my index.php page
    >>// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();

//

   The application.php is already inside the library/zend package...
   This is my application.ini
    [production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
    phpSettings.display_errors = 0
    includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
     appnamespace = "Application"
    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

    [staging : production]

    [testing : production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
     phpSettings.display_errors = 1



    [development : production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
I just dont understand why it cant get that file yet it is inside the Zend    folder...
```

Everything looks just fine from my perspective
 Pliz help...thanks in advance

Comment: the application.ini is in place....am not sure about the access denied..how do i go about the access denied part..?

Comment: Check you decompressed Zend Library in the right place.

Comment: hey..i got it..i just copied the zend folder and pasted inside my projects   library folder and boom it worked...Thanks alot...In my previous installation i did not have to do this..is this the way it shuld  be..Thanks alot..

Comment: @user2435822 Check the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ZF library folder is in you include path in php.ini.

On my machine (typical windows + xampp), the file can be found in c:\xampp\php\php.ini

Look for the line:

```
include_path = "."
```

and change it to include you ZF library path

```
include_path = ".;C:\path\to\Zend\Parent\Directory";
```

If your ZF libraries are located in C:\xampp\ZF\library\Zend, the include path should be "C:\xampp\ZF\library".